# Assembly(Plugin) is not triggering on web roles (custom entity) update in contact entity Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom entity **Web Role** in dynamics 365 and it's integrated with the  **contact** entity to assign web roles to each contact. you can see how web role is used in contact in the below image.

[image]

And Web Role entity has N:N relationships as given in below image.

[image]

I have created an Assembly(Plugin) using the plugin registration tool (see step config in below image) which is calling third-party API when we update a contact in dynamics 365 and it's working fine on an update of any data of contact except Web role. if we add/remove web role of contact and save, the assembly is not actioning.

[image]

So please help me, what should I need to do to call plugin on web role update in dynamics 365 contact.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the trigger wrong. As Webrole and Contact has N:N relationship, The Trigger is Associate and dessociate.

Take a look at this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/entity-operations-associate-disassociate)

Also [this article](https://www.adyatantech.com/blogs/associate-and-disassociate-multiple-records-to-a-parent-grid-in-dynamics-365-using-plugin) shall be helpful